# xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported. How to export the .xlsx file to a Dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am getting this below error while I am trying to read a .xlsx file into Pandas Dataframe.
ERROR :

```
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported
```

the code used for reading the excel sheet into Pandas Dataframe is below:

```
ip_data = pd.read_excel(file_path)
print(ip_data)
```

can anyone suggest a possible solution to export the excel file to Dataframe.

P.S: I have already installed the required version of xlrd too. i.e >=1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Install openpyxl with

```
$ pip install openpyxl
```

Read it with engine='openpyxl',

```
ip_data = pd.read_excel(
         file_path
         engine='openpyxl',
    )
```

Take a look here about [openpyxl's](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) documentation